# Return value of callback function to main function

Tags: node.js

I'm using this [crawler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler) library to crawler a specific page and get the website title, for this I'm working with express and that library:

```
app.get('/crawler/', function(req, res){

var returnedTitle = crawlerTest(req.query.urlsite);
res.send({'title' : returnedtitle});
res.end();

});

function crawlerTest(urlsite){
var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections : 10,
    // This will be called for each crawled page
    callback : function (error, res, done) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            var $ = res.$;
            // $ is Cheerio by default
            //a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
            console.log($("title").text());
        }
        done();
    }
});

// Queue just one URL, with default callback
c.queue(urlsite);
}
```

In the code above I am using the basic example of the library itself.

In this case, the `crawlerTest` function enters the site and can extract the page title.

But there is a flaw, I need to find a way to return the website title `$("title").text()` straight to the `crawlerTest` function, so that the `returnedTitle` variable can store the website title to send in response to `res.send()`

I know we should always call `done()` function for each crawled page, but I can't think of a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked I just returned promise from crawlerTest function.

```
app.get('/crawler/', async function(req, res){

    var returnedTitle =  await crawlerTest(req.query.urlsite);
    res.send({'title' : returnedtitle});
    res.end();

    });

    function crawlerTest(urlsite){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            var c = new Crawler({
                maxConnections : 10,
                // This will be called for each crawled page
                callback : function (error, res, done) {
                    if(error){
                        console.log(error);
                        reject(error);
                    }else{
                        var $ = res.$;
                        // $ is Cheerio by default
                        //a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
                        console.log($("title").text());
                        resolve($("title").text());
                    }
                    done();
                }
            });

            // Queue just one URL, with default callback
            c.queue(urlsite);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Work as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the res object to the crawlerTest function, and do `res.send({title: $("title").text()})` there, something like.

```
app.get('/crawler/', function(req, res){
  crawlerTest(req.query.urlsite, res);
});

function crawlerTest(urlsite, serverRes){
  var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections : 10,
    // This will be called for each crawled page
    callback : function (error, res, done) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            var $ = res.$;
            // $ is Cheerio by default
            //a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
            console.log($("title").text());
            serverRes.send({'title' : returnedtitle});

        }
        serverRes.end();
        done();
    }
  });

  // Queue just one URL, with default callback
  c.queue(urlsite);
}
```

Comment: Your code works, but in my case I need to return the title to `crawlerTest` function....